# Creating correct connection string to database on VM

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, connection-string

I have running Virtual Machine on my computer that has SQL Server Database to which I need to connect from my computer.

I'm confused on how to build connection string.

Instance name of SQL Server is SHAREPOINT. I connect to the database with localhost\SHAREPOINT (Windows Authentication).
Database name is SharePoint_Config_42e863cc-dc6c-477b-8323-9c16b7e9e53a.

I don't know what should I put for Data Source, which IP address to take?

I think my connection string would look something like this in the end:

```
Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\SHAREPOINT;Initial Catalog=SharePoint_Config_42e863cc-dc6c-477b-8323-9c16b7e9e53a;
```

Also, I think it's important to say, account on VM has username and password.

Comment: The IP address depends how you've setup your VM network. Are you using Hyper-V and is the VM attached to the external network with allow OS management? Also, you'll need to create a firewall rule for the named instance TCP port and allow UDP 1434 traffic too in order to connect to the instance by name.

Comment: Yes @DanGuzman, it's Hyper-V and VM is connected through external network adapter. Do I need to create that, if my Firewall is off? Btw, I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 on VM.

Comment: In that case, you should be able to connect specifying the VM's IP address in your example connection string, along with the SQL userid and password. Of course, the SQL instance needs to be configured to allow remote connections too.